# apache and index.php laravel routing

Tags: php, apache, lamp, digital-ocean, administration

After hours on forums I didn't find a solution so I hope you can help.

I setup a LAMP server and I'm trying to fix the routing cause to enable routing I need to add IP/**index.php**/route

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/html.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
 </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also ran

```
sudo a2ensite html.conf
sudo a2dissite 000.default.conf
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And I restarted the server- please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride  All in

```
 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```